# mysql delimit and search column data

Tags: mysql

MySQL version = 5.7.29
I want to do a MySQL search on a column which has delimited data. For example:

> 'field_black:1, field_white:2, field1_black:5, field_green:3'

I want a function which takes input the color and returns only the delimited values which do not have the input color.

```
func(input, color, delimiter)
func('field_black:1, field_white:2, field1_black:5, field1_green:3', 'black', ',') = 'field_white:2, field1_green:3'
```

This is pretty easy to implement in python using string split on delimiter and returning result set where the color is not in the given input.

```
def func(inp, col, delim):
    inp = inp.split(delim)

    res = []
    for data in inp:
       if col not in data:
           res.append(data)
    return (','.join(res))
```

Can anyone help me with an equivalent implementation in MySQL.
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION func (input TEXT, color TEXT, delimiter CHAR(1))
RETURNS TEXT 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE piece TEXT;
DECLARE result TEXT DEFAULT '';
/* SET color = CONCAT('field_', color); */     /* uncomment if needed */    
    REPEAT
        SET piece = SUBSTRING_INDEX(input, delimiter, 1);
        SET input = SUBSTRING(input FROM 2 + LENGTH(piece) FOR LENGTH(input));
        IF NOT LOCATE(color, piece) THEN
            SET result = CONCAT(result, delimiter, TRIM(piece));
        END IF;
    UNTIL input = ''
    END REPEAT;
    RETURN TRIM(BOTH delimiter FROM result);
END
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ea7d197517c5e4d9bdd211d727acf8db)

PS. Of course you may use multi-char delimiter if needed - alter input parameter type simply.

Answer (score 0):

Just cracked this after a few iterations due to unfamiliarity with MySQL syntax. This is unnecessarily complicated though.

Answer by Akina is more simple and elegant: [mysql delimit and search column data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62425579/mysql-delimit-and-search-column-data/62426938#62426938)

```
CREATE FUNCTION `new_function`(input longtext, col TEXT, delim CHAR(1)) RETURNS longtext CHARSET utf8
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
declare result longtext  default '';
declare piece longtext  default '';
declare inptext longtext default '';

set inptext = input;

while (substring_index(inptext,delim,1) = '') = 0 DO
    set piece = substring_index(inptext,delim,1);
    IF NOT LOCATE(col, piece) THEN
        set result = concat(result, piece, delim);
    END IF;
    set inptext = substr(inptext, length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(inptext, '|', 1) ) + 2);
END WHILE;


set result = left(result, length(result) -1);
RETURN result;

END
```